# Can't get simple converter to work when using on a bound String

Tags: c#, wpf, string, binding, converters

I have the following converter defined (C#):

```
class BodyValueConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string s = value.ToString();
        int prefixLength;
        if (!int.TryParse(parameter.ToString(), out prefixLength))
            return s;
        return s.Substring(0, prefixLength);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

This will start at the start of the string being passed and will return the amount of characters I specify as a parameter.

In my XAML I have instanced the converter:

```
<local:BodyValueConverter x:Key="BodyValueConverter"/>
```

In attempting to use this converter in a textblock I get an error:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="AppointmentTemplate">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Subject}"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Subject, Converter={StaticResource BodyValueConverter}, ConverterParameter=1}"></TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

The error is:

> XAMLParseException: Provide value on 'System.Windows.Markup.StaticResourceHolder' threw an exception.

The first textblock works fine to display subject. The 2nd line is what gives me the exception.

Comment: What's the order of your objects in your XAML? The Converter has to be defined prior to actually being used, so be sure your converter is above your `DataTemplate` in your `Resources`, or switch to using a `DynamicResource` instead of a `StaticResource`

Comment: Perfect Rachel!! Sorted it! Didn't think the order of resources mattered to be honest, I'm glad to have learnt it. Thanks a lot. Maybe post as an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's the order of your objects in your XAML?

The `Converter` has to be defined prior to actually being used, so be sure your `<Converter>` is above your `<DataTemplate>` in your `Resources`

Another alternative is to switch to using a `DynamicResource` instead of a `StaticResource`, since a `DynamicResource` is evaluated when it is needed, not when the XAML is loaded

Answer (score 1):

That error is usually thrown when it can't find the static resource you are looking for.  You'll need to define that in your static resources.

```
<Window 
  .... snip ...
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YourLocalNamespace"
  <Window.Resources>
    <local:BodyValueConverter x:Key="BodyValueConverter"/>
  </Window.Resources>
  .... snip ....
  <DataTemplate x:Key="AppointmentTemplate">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Subject}"></TextBlock>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Subject, Converter={StaticResource BodyValueConverter}, ConverterParameter=1}"></TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
  </DataTemplate>
</Window>
```

Note: This is when you are defining it in Window. You could define it elsewhere.

If this isn't the issue.... to find a more detailed explanation of what the parse error is... check the inner exception text.

Comment: It was simply down to the ordering of my resources. Thanks a lot for your reply anyway.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. It wouldn't be defined yet.

Comment: My bad for not providing necessary specifics regarding ordering of my XAML.

Comment: No, you had an issue you didn't know what it was so you wouldn't know what you needed to put in your question unless you stuck EVERYTHING in.  If you would have did that you probably wouldn't have gotten any answers =)